# Vertical align sentence in div Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment, vertical-alignment

So I am using the latest realse of Bootstrap and I have the following div

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-2 col-lg-8 memory textContainer">
    <p>{{ $memory->description }}</p>
</div>
```

The maxiumum sentence is 200 characters long so won't fit in one line.For my vertical align I have the following CSS.

```
.textContainer {
    height: 200px;
    line-height: 200px;
}

.textContainer p {
    height: 200px;
}
```

This is working but not when the sentence is longer then one line because then spaceing between the two lines is 200px aswell like the following image.

[image]

Is there a work around for this problem? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What sort of cross browser compatibility are you after? The accepted answer wont work well in browsers that don't support css3 transforms. If you need to support older browsers try this:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-2 col-lg-8 memory textContainer">

  <div class="centered">
    <p>{{ $memory->description }}</p>
  </div>

</div>

.textContainer {
height: 200px;
}
/* The ghost, nudged to maintain perfect centering */
.textContainer:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: -0.25em; /* Adjusts for spacing */
}

/* The element to be centered, can also be of any width and height */ 
.centered {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

ref: https://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/

Comment: This is even better, thank you for sharing because you can do it for ul aswell. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you?

```css
.textContainer {
    height: 200px;
    background: silver;
    position: relative;
}
.textContainer p {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="textContainer">
    <p>content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much, now need to know why i worked!